# How to get content with their taxonomy term name and id?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

Hello I have created content type product. I also add Taxonomy with name "category". I add field in with term reference in product content type. Now I want to get all content with taxonomy name and id which have content type named "product" using query in Drupal 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have created your view and added all the fields that your are interested in, add a filter on your taxonomy field "category":

- choose the vocabulary type that matches your taxomomy term
- choose the selection type Dropdown or Autocomplete.
- select the operator "is one of" and select/fill the value "product" in the associated form.
- Apply to display.

The query will return all the content that have your taxonomy category "product".